# Why do external docs show up before servers in Swagger UI?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I have the following OpenAPI YAML definition. The `externalDocs` section is underneath the `servers` section but it shows up before the server in the preview in the Swagger Editor (https://editor.swagger.io/). Why is that?

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Service
  description: >- 
    Service description
  version: '1.0'
  termsOfService: >-
    https://pdf/API_Developer_Agreement.pdf
  contact:
    email: 'contact@contact.com'
    name: 'contact Europa'
servers:
  - url: http://api.example.com/v1
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Main (production) server
  - url: http://staging-api.example.com
    description: Optional server description, e.g. Internal staging server for testing
externalDocs:
  description: "externalDocs"
  url: 'https://externalDocs'

paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of users.
      description: Optional extended description in CommonMark or HTML
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A JSON array of user names
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: 
                type: array
                items: 
                  type: string
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display order of the `info`, `externalDocs` and `servers` sections in Swagger UI is predefined and does not depend on their order in the YAML/JSON file.

However, individual servers in `servers`, individual paths and operations in `paths`, and individual properties in schemas are by default displayed in the same order as they are listed in your API definition.